# Черный экран при установке Kali

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

Пытаюсь поставить Kali Linux в Virtualbox. На самом компе система 64-битная. Кали пробовал ставить и 64 и 32.

При попытке установки 32 - после выбора "Install" - вылезает:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae
Unable to boot — please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

Если в настройках машины выбираю

```
Включить PAE/NX
```

То после нажатия на "Install" просто появляется черный экран и больше ничего не происходит.

Пасаны говорят, что надо в биосе включить виртуализацию - но у меня в биосе её нет.

А вот такое вылезает когда пытаюсь поставить 64:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64? but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for you CPU
```

Что делать? Как дальше жить?

Проц: `intel(r) pentium(r) cpu b960 @ 2.20ghz`

Comment: Судя по первому сообщению, процессор в вашем компьютере был выпущен раньше, чем Pentium Pro, а потому не поддерживает используемой Kali технологии [PAE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAE).

Comment: Собери образ без PAE http://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso Прокрути до **Building Kali Linux for older i386 architecture**

Comment: В виртуалбоксе нужно выбрать 64bit процессор, чтобы в bios появилось, нужно загуглить hardware virtualization и описание вашего железа (материнская плата или модель ноута), с высокой вероятностью есть или апдейт биоса или утилита включающая флаг. И ещё момент - у вас host os 32бит ?

Comment: @zb', host os у меня 64. Никаких заплаток для биоса похоже нет

Comment: @Alex78191 скачал готовую сборку 'kali-linux-light-2017-W23-i386.iso' . Всё равно просит PAE

Comment: Какая ОС в настройках виртуалбокса выбрана?

Comment: @andreymal сейчас Дебиан (32 бит). Пробовал выбирать "Линус / Другая" разницы нет

Comment: @РашенБеар потому что PAE не отключен, я сказал нужно самому собрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вам нужно собрать образ без PAE**

В ISO Kali Linux i386 включен PAE. Если вам нужно ядро ​​по умолчанию для старого оборудования с отключенным PAE, вам нужно будет пересобрать ISO Kali Linux.  Параметр `686-pae` необходимо изменить на `586` в **auto/config** следующим образом:

Сначала установите необходимые программы и скачайте исходники.

```
apt install git live-build cdebootstrap debootstrap 
git clone git://git.kali.org/live-build-config.git
```

Затем сделайте изменение в auto / config для выбора соответствующей архитектуры:

```
cd live-build-config 
sed -i 's/686-pae/586/g' auto/config
```

Наконец, запустите свою сборку.

```
./build.sh --distribution kali-rolling --arch i386
```

---

http://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso – Building Kali Linux for older i386 architecture